# windows batch file running C# program at intervals

Tags: c#, sql-server, batch-file

Step 1: I have 5 C# programs that run on a Friday evening using Task Scheduler. If all run successfully I update a status table in SQL SERVER database with Program Name(all begin with NAMESEARCH) that completed running with status =1. If there was exception, I update the Status table with programname and Status=0.

```
Create table Run_Status(ProgramName varchar(500) not null, Status int not null);
```

In Step 2: Write a bat file to run C# program (Name.exe)
My c# program does this: I check the Run_Status table, if count for programname like 'NAMESEARCH%' is 5. Then check if all Status =1 and then continue with other processing

My question: How can I write a bat file that runs every hour to check until  count for programname like 'NAMESEARCH%' is 5 or in other words, Step1 is complete.

Right this is all I have in my bat file

```
@ECHO OFF
SET Header=-----------------------------------------------------

start "" "C:\Projects\Name\Name\bin\Debug\Name.exe"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
echo %header%
Echo There has been an error.
echo.
pause
goto end)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
ECHO Success
goto end
}
:end
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo %header%
echo END
REM cd ..
```

THanks
R

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You already have 5 programs that get executed at regular intervals interacting with your database and now you are asking how to write a 6th program to get executed at regular intervals and interact with the database? I would have thought after writing the first 5, that would be an easy task. What is different this time?

Comment: @nvoigt, 6th program, gets executed by bat file not task scheduler. It needs to check if all 5 programs completed running. When I run the bat file(i.e 6th C# program), If I have only 2 records that start with NAMESEARCH, then I want the bat file to run again after 1 hour to check for completion of other 3 C# programs.

Comment: Does `name.exe` return any errorlevel or text output? What is the meaning/content?

Comment: @MCND, name.exe is lucene index program- builds index to the rows inserted by my first 5 programs that run from Task scheduler. I just log exceptions to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Jenkins to run these jobs for you?

Jenkins is free ( as in beer), with lots of plugins to make your life easier. Although it is labeled as a CI Server, it could automate any type of batch command using a schedule or triggers.
You could have batch commands run sequentially, with reporting on errors, or no errors. Jenkins can generate email or do other things depending on job outcomes.

To answer specifically your question: I would create 2 jobs in jenkins, the first one executing a windows batch on the hour, checking for the SQL results you want, and the second to the other processing you mentioned.

Set the second job to be triggered by the first job's successful completion.

Trust me, **Jenkins is easy to use.** I keep finding new things for it to do that makes my life easier.

Want to switch on you coffee machine at 5am, and get a message when its ready? Jenkins can do that too with some help from a Raspberry Pi and IFTTT.

http://jenkins-ci.org/category/tags/tutorial